# regex to select a sentence based on the presence of more than one word

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I can select a sentence from a single word using this regex:

```
[^.]* word [^.]*\.
```

How can I select a sentence based on two or more words in a conditional way?

For example, select sentence if word A and (word B or word C) are present.

Supposing word A = "*studies*", word B = "*suggest*", word C = "*evidence*", then the following sentence would be selected because 2 words are matched:

> Our **studies** **suggest** that ACTN3 R577X genotype is a modifier of
>   clinical phenotype in DMD patients.

But the following sentence, since it only has matched one word would not be selected:

> Moreover, **studies** of the RR genotype have shown a downward linear
>   trend with increased incidences of ankle sprain.

Comment: Can you give some examples with expected output?

Comment: That depends on the regex flavor. What's yours?

Comment: Wiktor: javascript

Comment: You'd better extract all sentences with say `/[^.!?]+/g` and then check with `indexOf` if the words are present. Else, after extracting all the sentences, use `/^(?=.*\bstudies\b)(?=.*\bsuggest\b)(?=.\bevidence\b)/` regex to get those that have all 3 words. You should think of using `indexOf` if you want to check for *at least* n words in a sentence, a regex will become unwieldly if you need at least 8 out of 20.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use:

```
\bworda\b[^.!?]*\b(?:wordb|wordc)\b
```

This will match a sentence if it contains `worda` **and** `wordb` **or** `wordc` if there are not separated by a punctuation.

If you want to match the words in any order:

```
^(?=[^.!?]*\bstudies\b)(?=[^.!?]*\b(?:suggest|evidence)\b)[^.!?]*\.$
```

```js
var test = [
'Our studies suggest that ACTN3 R577X genotype is a modifier of clinical phenotype in DMD patients.',
'Moreover, studies of the RR genotype have shown a downward linear trend with increased incidences of ankle sprain.',
'Moreover, studies of the evidence of ankle sprain.',
'Moreover, evidence of the studies of ankle sprain.',
'Moreover, the incidences of ankle sprain.'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^(?=[^.!?]*\bstudies\b)(?=[^.!?]*\b(?:suggest|evidence)\b)[^.!?]*\.$/i.test(a);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
\b\[a-zA-Z]+\b(?=\s*(test|example))
```

**\b** is a word boundary, it allows you to perform a "words only" search.

**[a-zA-Z]** will match any word (sequence of one or more characters).

**(?=)** is a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**(test|example)** will be true if it matches either test or example.

Working example at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OUjQW8/1).

Comment: You mean [^.]* (test|example) [^.]*\.

Comment: Did you try it on examples given?